# Why won't my div expand to accommodate my table?

Tags: html, html-table

I have a dynamic table that expands in height at various times.  It's wrapped in a DIV tag.  The DIV tag does not expand with the table.  Is there a trick to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing any code, it sounds like you needs a clearing `br` under the `table`.

Add `<br style="clear:both;" />` after the `table` and before the closing `</div>`.

Of course, you should place that CSS in a class and add it to your stylesheet.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried setting the width and height on the div to auto? Some brief googling seems to suggest that position also needs to be set, so either position:absolute or position:relative should work fine.

I can revise my answer if you post either code or a link to the page you're having the problem on.

```
#yourDiv
{
  position:absolute;
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
}
```